# Управление таймером с кнопки

Tags: qt

Как можно управлять таймером при помощи кнопки:

У меня основная часть(чтение данных и постройка графиков) крутится в таймере(обновляется раз в секунду):

```
connect(tmr, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateData()));
```

Хочу сделать так: нажал кнопку - запустился таймер, нажал еще раз - остановилась работа таймера и обнулились все данные.

Comment: Ловите клик кнопки и меняете состояние таймера через методы [start](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtimer.html#start-1) и stop, ну и попутно делаете другие действия, к примеру очищения данных

Answer (score 4):

```
void onButtonClick()
{
    if (!timer.isActive())
        timer.start();
    else
    {
        timer.stop();
        data.clear();
    }
}
```

Через лямбду:

```
QObject::connect(&myButton, &QPushButton::clicked, this, (this, myData)[] {
    if (this->myTimer.isActive())
        this->myTimer.start();
    else {
        this->myTimer.stop();
        myData.clear
    } } );
```